# Table valued parameter in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a table type in SQL Server 2008, but I'm getting this error:

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.*

But I don't find anything wrong.

This is the code:

```
CREATE TYPE DeptType AS TABLE
(
    DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(30)
);
GO
```

Kindly tell me where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are hooked up to a SQL2008 server and not 2005?

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the database name or schema name and try.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.DeptType AS TABLE
(
    DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(30)
);
GO
```